# Filterable Interface ok, but BaseAdapter's getview getting wrong position

Tags: android, listview

I implemented a `SearchView` and a custom `Filter` to filter a `ListView` in my app. I am facing this issue: when I filter `ListView` after typing in `SeachView` field and click on an item, it opens a new activity as it should, but they get all wrong data position. I tried to put in the onclickListener `i.putExtra("word", word);` but it gets the wrong position of "word" string.

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements
    SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {

    ListView list;
    SearchView mSearchView;

    ArrayList<Vocabulary> vocabularylist;
    ListViewAdapter adapter;
    String[] definition;
    String[] word;
    String[] example;
    int[] flag;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
        setContentView(R.layout.listview_main);

        definition = new String[] { "loira burra", 
                                    "arrasa-corações",
                                    "vagabundo"};

        word = new String[] { "bimbo", 
                              "heartthrob",
                              "good-for-nothing"};

        example = new String[] { "✎ She's a real bimbo.", 
                                 "✎ He's a real heartthrob.",
                                 "✎ What are you doing wasting time here? Get a job, you good-for-nothing!"};

        flag = new int[] { R.drawable.bimbo, 
                           R.drawable.heartthrob, 
                           R.drawable.vagabundo};

        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
        mSearchView = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.search_view);

        vocabularylist = new ArrayList<Vocabulary>();
        for (int i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
            Vocabulary vocabulary = new Vocabulary(word[i], definition[i], example[i],
                    flag[i]);
            vocabularylist.add(vocabulary);
        }

        adapter = new ListViewAdapter(getApplicationContext(), vocabularylist, word, definition, example, flag);

        list.setAdapter(adapter);
        list.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
        setupSearchView();
        // Capture ListView item click
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SingleItemView.class);
                // Pass all data definition
                Vocabulary vocabulary = (Vocabulary) adapter.getItem(position);

                i.putExtra("definition", vocabulary.getDefinition());
                // Pass word
                i.putExtra("word", vocabulary.getWord());
                // Pass example
                i.putExtra("example", vocabulary.getExample());
                // Pass flag
                i.putExtra("flag", vocabulary.getFlag());
                // Pass position
                i.putExtra("position", position);
                // Open SingleItemView.java Activity
                startActivity(i);
            }
        }); 
    }

    private void setupSearchView() {
        mSearchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
        mSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
        mSearchView.setSubmitButtonEnabled(true); 
        mSearchView.setQueryHint("Search Here");
    }

    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
        adapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
        return false;
    }

    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

ListViewAdapter

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {
    Context context;
    String[] word;
    String[] definition;
    String[] example;
    int[] flag;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    ArrayList<Vocabulary> vocabularylist;
    ArrayList<Vocabulary> mStringFilterList;
    ValueFilter valueFilter;

    public ListViewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Vocabulary> vocabularylist, String[] word, String[] definition,
            String[] example, int[] flag) {
        this.context = context;
        this.word = word;
        this.definition = definition;
        this.example = example;
        this.flag = flag;
        this.vocabularylist = vocabularylist;
        mStringFilterList = vocabularylist;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return vocabularylist.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return vocabularylist.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return vocabularylist.indexOf(getItem(position));
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        TextView txtword;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item, parent, false);

        // Locate the TextViews in listview_item.xml
        txtword = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.word);

        Vocabulary vocabulary = vocabularylist.get(position);
        txtword.setText(vocabulary.getWord());

        return itemView;
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        if (valueFilter == null) {
            valueFilter = new ValueFilter();
        }
        return valueFilter;
    }

    private class ValueFilter extends Filter {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

            if (constraint != null && constraint.length() > 0) {
                ArrayList<Vocabulary> filterList = new ArrayList<Vocabulary>();
                for (int i = 0; i < mStringFilterList.size(); i++) {
                    if ((mStringFilterList.get(i).getWord().toUpperCase())
                            .contains(constraint.toString().toUpperCase())) {

                        Vocabulary vocabulary = new Vocabulary(mStringFilterList.get(i)
                                .getWord(), mStringFilterList.get(i)
                                .getDefinition(), mStringFilterList.get(i)
                                .getExample(), mStringFilterList.get(i)
                                .getFlag());

                        filterList.add(vocabulary);
                    }
                }
                results.count = filterList.size();
                results.values = filterList;
            } else {
                results.count = mStringFilterList.size();
                results.values = mStringFilterList;
            }
            return results;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
                FilterResults results) {
            vocabularylist = (ArrayList<Vocabulary>) results.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Vocabulary

```
public class Vocabulary {
    String word;
    int flag;
    String definition;
    String example;

    Vocabulary(String word, String definition, String example, int flag) {
        this.word = word;
        this.definition = definition;
        this.example = example;
        this.flag = flag;
    }

    public String getDefinition() {
        return definition;
    }

    public void setDefinition(String definition) {
        this.definition = definition;
    }

    public String getWord() {
        return word;
    }

    public void setWord(String word) {
        this.word = word;
    }



    public String getExample() {
        return example;
    }

    public void setExample(String example) {
        this.example = example;
    }

    public int getFlag() {
        return flag;
    }

    public void setFlag(int flag) {
        this.flag = flag;
    }

}
```

SingleItemView

```
public class SingleItemView extends Activity {
    // Declare Variables
    TextView txtdefinition;
    TextView txtword;
    TextView txtexample;
    ImageView imgflag;
    String[] definition;
    String[] word;
    String[] example;
    int[] flag;
    int position;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.singleitemview);
        // Retrieve data from MainActivity on listview item click
        Intent i = getIntent();

        position = i.getExtras().getInt("position");

        definition = i.getStringArrayExtra("definition");

        word = i.getStringArrayExtra("word");

        example = i.getStringArrayExtra("example");
        // Get the list of flag
        flag = i.getIntArrayExtra("flag");


        txtdefinition = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.definition);
        txtword = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.word);
        txtexample = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.example);


        imgflag = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.flag);


        txtdefinition.setText(definition[position]);
        txtword.setText(word[position]);
        txtexample.setText(example[position]);


        imgflag.setImageResource(flag[position]);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct about the location of the issue. Problem is those source arrays are not being filtered so the indexes do not match the indexes of the adapter which is being filtered.
Rewrite `onItemClick()` as follows:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
        int position, long id) {
    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SingleItemView.class);

    Vocabulary voc = (Vocabulary) adapter.getItem(position);

    i.putExtra("definition", voc.getDefinition());
    // Pass word
    i.putExtra("word", voc.getWord());
    // Pass example
    i.putExtra("example", voc.getExample());
    // Pass flag
    i.putExtra("flag", voc.getFlag());
    // Pass position
    i.putExtra("position", position);
    // Open SingleItemView.java Activity
    startActivity(i);
}
```

This only passes the values that you should need in the other `SingleItemView` activity. Not the whole arrays.

Also, a couple improvements you might want to consider is making the `Adapter` extend `ArrayAdapter<Vocabulary>` instead of `BaseAdapter` to avoid casting.
You could pass the whole `Vocabulary` object to the new `Activity` too if you make it implement `Parcelable` instead of passing the individual fields.

UPDATE:

Here are the changes that need to be made to `SingleItemView` as well. You do not need the whole arrays to show a single item so I updated the extras to pass the selected items values only.

```
public class SingleItemView extends Activity {
    // Declare Variables
    TextView txtdefinition;
    TextView txtword;
    TextView txtexample;
    ImageView imgflag;
    String definition;
    String word;
    String example;
    int flag;
    int position;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.singleitemview);
        // Retrieve data from MainActivity on listview item click
        Intent i = getIntent();

        position = i.getIntExtra("position", -1);
        definition = i.getStringExtra("definition");
        word = i.getStringExtra("word");
        example = i.getStringExtra("example");
        flag = i.getIntExtra("flag", -1);


        txtdefinition = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.definition);
        txtword = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.word);
        txtexample = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.example);


        imgflag = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.flag);


        txtdefinition.setText(definition);
        txtword.setText(word);
        txtexample.setText(example);


        imgflag.setImageResource(flag);

    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help, but after I rewrote onItemClick and ran my application, every time I click on item, the app is stopped and finished.

Comment: Did you rewrite the `SingleItemView` activity to get the intent extras as strings instead of string arrays? If not do that first. If you did then please include the stack trace from logcat with the error message as an edit to your question to see what went wrong.

Comment: I updated my `MainActivity` above (with all rewriting onItemClick) and I posted my `SingleItemView` activity. Take a look if it's ok. Thanks in advance.

Comment: OK I showed how to properly update the `SingleItemView` activity to no longer use the arrays. Assuming no typos this should fix the error you were having.